# React distinct key for a duplicated component

Tags: reactjs

I have a `perkProgress` prop that is always an integer of 0-3.
I am using Ramda's library for their `repeat` function to triplicate the creation of an Element 'once per'
`{R.repeat(<CheckCircle key={uid()} />, this.props.perkProgress)}`

My issue is I am not sure how to create a 'unique ID' for the `key` prop. I went to [UUID Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid%20%22uuid%20package) for assistance, but I'm still getting the same warning. It's like the `uid()` is rendering first to a static text, and then `.repeat()` is triplicating that -exact- value. I've tried `Math.random()` to test this theory and the same thing happens.

How are you supposed to assign a unique ID to something that is creating a duplicate component?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qq9p2qoz69) - I wasn't able to get `uid` to work in here, but to show I used `Math.random()` which you would expect to have different outcomes, but it is the same one each time.

Comment: Are you able to link code? Ideally via codesandbox.io

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin Done.

Comment: Ramda is memoizing the first call to be efficient. use `range` and `map` instead

Comment: @azium Was my exact issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a good idea to set up `Math.random` as the React element key since, on every render a new key will be generated an used which will affect react-performance. You could instead use `R.range(0, 3)` and map over it setting the value as key like

```
const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    {R.range(0, 3).map(key => <li key={key}>Hi</li>)}
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}</h2>
  </div>
);
```

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3v1zw34y0)**

P.S. `repeat` memoizes the value and hence you see the same key for every item being generated.

Comment: Thanks for the showcase. @azium actually corrected me as a reply to mine and it made perfect sense. I appreciate additional methods, for sure.